# Show that the function $u(x,y) =e^{x^2−y^2}\cos(2xy )$is harmonic. Find the harmonic conjugate v of u, up to addition of a constant.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functions, harmonic-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Show that the function $u(x,y) =e^{(x^2−y^2)}\cos(2xy)$ is harmonic. Find the harmonic conjugate of u, up to the addition of a constant. 
My question is how do you integrate this function?

My approach:
To show that $u(x,y)$ is harmonic it will need continuous 2nd order partial derivatives and that $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}=0$.
Therefore:

$\frac{du}{dx}=-2y\sin (2xy)e^{(x^2-y^2)}+2x\cos (2xy)e^{(x^2-y^2)}$ and $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=-4ye^{(x^2-y^2)}(x\sin (2xy)+y\cos (2xy))+4e^{(x^2-y^2)}x(-y\sin (2xy)+x\cos (2xy))+2\cos (2xy)e^{(x^2-y^2)}$

$\frac{du}{dy}=e^{(x^2-y^2)}y\cos (2xy)-2xe^{(x^2-y^2)}\sin (2xy)$

$\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}=4ye^{(x^2-y^2)}(y\cos (2xy)+2x\sin (2xy))-4e^{(x^2-y^2)}x^2\cos (2xy)-2e^{(x^2-y^2)}\cos (2xy)$

Hence $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}=0$ Now to find $v(x,y)$ so v is harmonic to u if the Cauchy Riemann equations are continuous and hold you can see that they are continuous, thus:

$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}=-2y\sin (2xy)e^{(x^2-y^2)}+2x\cos (2xy)e^{(x^2-y^2)}$

To find v we integrate $∫$$-2y\sin (2xy)e^{(x^2-y^2)}+2x\cos (2xy)e^{(x^2-y^2)}dy$ which brings me to my question, how do you integrate this function?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as complex-analysis, I think there's a vastly simpler approach. Notice that $x^2 - y^2$ and $2xy$ are the real and imaginary parts of $z^2$, respectively. What can you do with this?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry

Comment: What are the real and imaginary parts of $e^{z^2}$ if $z=x+iy$?

Comment: I get that, I should have been more clear,  I'm not sure how converting this into a complex integration would help

Comment: @ricky If you think through this a bit there is no need to integrate.

Comment: thank you, I've ended up solving this using an antiderivative etc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could integrate by parts.

What was hinted at in the comments is that if you can identify a function $f(z)$ holomorphic and $u=\Re f$ then $v=\Im f.$

Since $u=\Re \exp z^2$, we have $v=\Im \exp z^2 +\textrm{const.}= \exp \left( x^2-y^2\right) \sin 2xy + \textrm{const.}$